# glqq and grqq cause an error with the SCfigure environment

Tags: floats, quotation

I am trying to use quotation marks in the caption of a SCfigure (side caption figure). This is the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[outercaption]{sidecap}
\begin{document}
\begin{SCfigure}[4][!htbp]
    \caption{
        \glqq Text\grqq
    }
\end{SCfigure}
\end{document}
```

However, I get this error message:
Undefined control sequence. \end{SCfigure}
If I replace the line

```
\glqq Text\grqq
```

with

```
Text
```

I get no error message but the correct result:
[image: compiling result]

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load e.g. babel and ngerman to define the commands (glqq means german left double quote). I would recommend to use csquotes instead:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[outercaption]{sidecap}
\begin{document}
\begin{SCfigure}[4][!htbp]
    \caption{
        \glqq Text\grqq \enquote{Text}
    }
\end{SCfigure}
\end{document}
```

[image]